# Web based chat in asp.net , using ajax timers , will it perform for large number of users

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

as all we know that we can create very simple chat using ajax timer & web service , it runs well for few users .

i want to leaverage same idea for site where 5000+ users will be there in chat room , messages are stored in queue hold in memory * dispatched as user request that is through java script timers calling page method or service ,

*how well it will perform* ? i know GTalk implements XMPP protocol(jabber) for the web chat 
seems it will be difficult to got XMPP way ?

Any guidence ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not perform well unless you use something like [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)).

This requires you to get rid of the conventional HTTP servers and use an Event based one ([NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/), [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/), [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)).